# React native: Function to clear application's cache

Tags: react-native

I want to clear application's cache when user log out. How can do it? please someone help.

Comment: Do you mean data you added using `AsyncStorage`?

Comment: @Joshua 
I mean data or cache which is we clear from app's settings.

Answer (score 0):

Heres how to remove all key value pairs in `AsyncStorage`

```js
/**
* Clean async storage
*/
async function cleanStorage(AsyncStorage){
    await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
    .then(keys => AsyncStorage.multiRemove(keys))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer!  I mean data or cache which is we clear from app's settings.

Comment: @Aytac you can't. Why would you want to do that?